# Phone number regex is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi have given phone no validation by including the given code

```
validates :phone, format: { with: /(\()?\d{3}(\))?(-|\s)?\d{3}(-|\s)\d{4}/}
```

When I give inpiut phone number as a `012-365-4987` then it works properly but when i give `(123) 856-9347` then it gives me error maximum 12 numbers. Please guide me about correct regex for these two phone numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**anchors**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#A) and try with the following pattern.

```
/\A\(?\d{3}\)?[- ]?\d{3}[- ]?\d{4}\z/
```

You also need to set a validation for length if you haven't already.